# how to get the saved items for a particular listitem in android?

Tags: android, listview, position, listitem

I am developing an application in which when user clicks on a item of a listview, a new page appears and in this page only the selected items are displayed. I mean for a particular list item only previously saved items are displayed.

In this new page i have 3 checkboxes. So when user clicks on a particular list item the new page display the checkbox with previous saved state for that particular item.

Now I dont know how to do that.

thanx in advance!!

This is my list onItemClick :-

```
OnItemClickListener ocl= new OnItemClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) 
                {
                    String name= list.get(arg2)[2];
                    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "session of.." + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Settings.setName(name);
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Profile.this, ProfileConfig.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            };
            lvChildProfile.setOnItemClickListener(ocl);
```

Now i want that when clicking the saved instance of checkbox appear.

Comment: @ Sneha Jain paste the code

Comment: What is it you need? a way to click on child? or a way to store the checkboxes results?

Comment: @AndersMetnik- i want when i click on particular child the saved settings for that child would appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the state within your objects itself.

```
Model implements Serializable {

    boolean isOptionOneChecked
    boolean isOptionTwoChecked
    boolean isOptionThreeChecked
    int id
    ...

    // Constructor
    // Getters & setters

}
```

This means your `Adapater` will have a list of objects from the type Model. How you want to display these in your `ListView`, can be done with a custom `Adapter` but that's not the real question.

When you click on an Item in your list, you can retrieve the object (like you already did) with

```
Model lModel = list.get(position);
```

In order to display the Model in a different `Activity`, you can send it along with your `Intent` as such:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Profile.this, ProfileConfig.class);
intent.putExtra("MySelectedObject", lModel);
startActivity(intent);
```

Because our class implements the `Serializable` interface, we can retrieve the object in our new `Activity` as followed:

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MySelectedObject");
```

You will have all the information about this object so you can create you layout accordingly.

Comment: thanx for your rply..i'll implement this and will let you know if it works for me or not.